# Simple button functionality stops after element removed

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jQuery and am trying to just create a load of simple test rows and be able to create new rows by clicking the add button and remove each row by clicking their corresponding 'delete' text. For some reason, whenever the first row is deleted, I can no longer add new rows.

Here's the HTML:

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='all'>
  <button class='add'>Add</button>
  <div class='row'>hi - <span class='del'>delete</span></div>
</div>
```

And the jQuery:

```
var row, add, rows;

$(document).ready(function(){  
  row = $('.row'); // problem? because it's not a clone?
  add = $('.add');
  rows = $('.row');
  add.on("click", function(){
    row.clone().appendTo($('#all')); // problem? because it's now gone?
    rows = $('.row');
    updateRows();
  });
});

function updateRows() {
  rows.on("click", ".del", function(){
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(1000, function(){
      $(this).remove();
    });
    rows = $('.row');
  });
}
```

I've also made a [CodePen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PXxGBm) if that helps. So my question is, why does the 'add' button stop working after the first row is deleted? I wonder whether once the first row is deleted, it can't be appended as the variable is then deleted, and if I'm right, how can you create a variable clone that stays even when it's deleted (if you know what I mean)?

Thanks for any help here - any explanations would be much appreciated.

Comment: I thought it might be this. I tried creating the row variable as the html of the row, but then you can't append it

Comment: Or you could change `row.clone()` to `$(".row").first().clone()` - but then you have the same problem if you delete *all* the rows - which you mitigate with a check on delete rows so last one can't be deleted.

Comment: You're also re-adding the del click handler each time - as you're using event delegation to a degree - change it to `$("all").on("click", ">.row>.del", ` then it can be added once (ie remove `updateRows()` completely and put inside doc ready.

Comment: I tried this here but still doesn't work: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MZzbqY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy the outerHTML of the row so that it's always available.  Using `$(".row").first().html()` only copies the inner HTML (so doesn't include the `class=row` part).

This gives you:

```
var row = $(".row").first().outerHTML(); // store first row
$('.add').on("click", function() {
  $("#all").append(row); 
});
```

Copy outerHTML taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4180972/2181514

As you're using event delegation for the del button, you only need to call this once, giving:

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.outerHTML = function() {
    return $(this).clone().wrap('<div></div>').parent().html();
  };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
  var row = $(".row").first().outerHTML(); // store first row
  $('.add').on("click", function() {
    $("#all").append(row);
  });

  $(document).on("click", ".row>.del", function() {
    $(this).closest(".row").fadeOut(1000, function() {
      $(this).remove();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='all'>
  <button class='add'>Add</button>
  <div class='row'>hi - <span class='del'>delete</span></div>
</div>
```

Updated codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qLQqJm

Answer (score 1):

If you delete the only row, there will be nothing inside of the variable `row` and therefore cause an error when you call `row.clone()`. You could set row = the html string of the row you wanted to `.clone()` and instead append the row as html to your div

```
var row, add, rows;

$(document).ready(function(){  
  row = '<div class="row">hi - <span class="del">delete</span</div>'; // changed to html string to append to div
  add = $('.add');
  rows = $('.row');
  add.on("click", function(){
    $('#all').append(row);
    rows = $('.row');
    updateRows();
  });
});

function updateRows() {
  rows.on("click", ".del", function(){
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(1000, function(){
      $(this).remove();
    });
    rows = $('.row');
  });
}
```

See updated codepen: (https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NeEbbL)

Comment: There's a reason you can't post without code - just copy the relevant code in to the answer so you don't get downvotes.

Comment: thanks, but in the case where I'm using it outside of this concise demo, doing what you've done (i.e. writing all the html manually) would be too verbose - is there another way?

Comment: What was wrong with `var rowtext = $(".row").first().html();` as the first line in doc.ready?

Comment: I can't get that to work, but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Yes, `.html()` only copies the inner html - I'll provide more details in a sec

Comment: Thanks - I tried row = $('.row').parent().first().html(); here https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KbrNGO but that failed - I used .parent() as I wanted the outerHTML

Comment: @freedomn-m Thanks for the tip, I added the code from the pen.